# WCF Service Retry

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way implementing a retry to the service when it sends a fault. lets say for eg:

```
Private Function SaveEmployee(emp as Empoyee)
Try
...
returnval = service.SaveEmployee(emp)
Catch ex as exception
'if exception requires retry eg:end point not found or database is not responding then
'call retry  func/class

RetryOperation(...) 

End Try

End Function
```

in the above sample how can I make a generic RetryOperation class which can take any function and call it 3 or 4 times with an interval before informing the user that the operation cannot be completed.

I'm hoping it's possible to make a generic method rather than have duplicate code in all the service call functions

any samples in C# or vb.net will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a call that you might want repeated if it fails why not use the Repeat functionality at once, if the service call is successful it will just be called once, if the service call fails it will retry x number of times, if it fails on the x:th time it will throw an exception

How about something like this, please note this is greatly simplified, you will need to add error handling and such:

Create your repeat method like this:

```
private void RepeatCall(int numberOfCalls, Action unitOfWork)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCalls; i++)
        {
        try
        {
            unitOfWork();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // decide which exceptions/faults should be retried and 
            // which should be thrown
            // and always throw when i == numberOfCalls
        }
     }
 }
```

Use it like this

```
try
{
    RepeatCall(3, () => 
                    {
                         MyServiceCall();
                    });

}
catch(....)
{
   // You'll catch here same as before since on the last try if the call
   // still fails you'll get the exception
}
```

Same thing in VB.NET

```
Private Sub RepeatCall(ByVal numberOfCalls As Integer, ByVal unitOfWork As Action)

    For i = 1 To numberOfCalls
        Try
            unitOfWork()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

Use it:

```
  Try
      RepeatCall(3, Sub()
                       MyServiceCall()
                    End Sub)

  Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm bit confused, are you suggesting by dafult to call RepeatCall and then it sends the exception?. what i wanted was the client function will call service function and if it throws an exception then only the RepeatCall should be called. or did I completely misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: I updated my answer see above, there is nothing preventing you from doing what you describe in your question using my code example, I've just described an approach I've used. This way you could put the retry logic in the RepeatCall method instead of duplicating it for every service call.

Comment: thanks again, that does make sense and eliminates repating catch-throw in methods.just wondering if RepeatCall can run on its own thread? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, it depends on what your requirements are of course i.e. does your code need to find out how the servicecall went in that case you need some type of syncing. I'd put the threading in the RepeatCall method I guess and add some type of callback so the main thread can get the eventual result of the operation (success or fail)